# Save each worksheet as new workbook

Tags: vba, excel

My below VBA function is used in a macro that creates new worksheets and saves them as per certain cell value in column C of a master workbook.

I want it, instead of creating new worksheets and pasting data in it, to save each in a new workbook within the same folder the master file is saved in.
I don't want new worksheets, I want new workbooks with the same data.

```
Private Function GetWorksheet(sName As String) As Worksheet
On Error Resume Next
Dim oSh As Worksheet
Set oSh = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(sName)
If oSh Is Nothing Then
    Set oSh = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add(after:=oShM)
    oSh.Name = sName
    oShM.Rows(1).Copy Destination:=oSh.Rows(1) ' Copy header
End If
Set GetWorksheet = oSh
End Function
```

Comment: Been here long enough to know better.

Comment: Where is the question?   I want to read questions.  I don't want people to tell what they want and don't want, without asking a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure I know exactly what you are looking for but, assuming you want to save each worksheet in a workbook as a new file, you could try something like the below:

```
Sub CopyWorksheets()

Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    ws.Copy
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs ("C:\YourDirectory\" & ws.Name)
    ActiveWorkbook.Close
Next ws


End Sub
```